# How can I find out what jQuery version I’m using?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My page loads jQuery. Is there any way to find out which version of jQuery that is?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use either `$().jquery;` or `$.fn.jquery`

Which will return a string containing the version number, e.g. 1.6.2.

Answer (score 6):

Just open Chrome Console or Firebug and type while in your page

```
$().jquery;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
alert($().jquery);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can know the version by using:

```
jQuery.fn.jquery
```