# How do i figure out the version of JQuery UI from version of jquery-ui-rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, rubygems, gemfile

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  In my Gemfile, I have

```
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.7'
…
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

How do I figure out what version of JQuery UI I’m using?

Comment: Per my comment to the other answer, that tells me the version of the Gem but that is different than the version of JQuery UI.  I want to know the version of JQuery UI correspoding to the gem.

Comment: Google "what jquery version am i using" or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973941/how-to-check-what-version-of-jquery-is-loaded or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423864/how-can-i-find-out-what-jquery-version-im-using-without-using-jquery or https://api.jquery.com/jquery-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look in the file [VERSIONS.md](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails/blob/master/VERSIONS.md), in which you can see the following (top five lines):

```
5.0.5   1.11.4
5.0.4   1.11.3
5.0.3   1.11.2
5.0.2   1.11.2
5.0.1   1.11.1
```

From the JQuery UI Rails [README](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails/blob/master/README.md) file:

> See VERSIONS.md to see which versions of jquery-ui-rails bundle which
>   versions of jQuery UI.

Answer (score 1):

```
bundle show jquery-ui-rails
```

This command will show you which version of that gem is being used in your project. You can also inspect your Gemfile.lock file or type

```
bundle show
```

to display all the gems being used.

To see the version of the jquery-ui plugin being used by any website, you can open the console tab in the developers tools of your browser and then type:

```
$.ui
```

Comment: That shows the version of the Gem, but not necessarily of JQuery-UI, right?  The lock file says "jquery-ui-rails (5.0.5)" but there is no such thing as JQuery UI 5.0.5.  My question was about jquery UI, not the gem per se.

Comment: That command will show you the gem version.

The easiest way to inspect the version being used in a website is asking directly. Open your browsers inspector (in google chrome by inspect element with the option click or cmd+alt+i) and then selecting the console tab. There you type  $.ui (and then enter)  and you will be able to see the version of the jquery-ui

Answer (score 0):

1. Use bundle show to know the version of jquery gem -

   ```
   bundle show jquery
   ```

   It will list something like -

   ```
   1 : jquery-rails
   2 : jquery-ui-rails
   3 : rails-jquery-autocomplete
   0 : - exit -
   ```
2. Select the appropriate option. In my system on selection of 2(jquery-ui-rails) it displayed -

   ```
   .../jquery-ui-rails-6.0.1
   ```
3. Check the gem to jquery version mapping @ https://github.com/jquery-ui-rails/jquery-ui-rails/blob/master/VERSIONS.md . In my case it was

   ```
   Gem      jQuery UI
   6.0.1    1.12.1
   ```

Note: I have combined @Hans Findel and @MarsAtomic answer.